# opensips-1.6: recv queue full

Tags: opensips

I am using opensips-1.6 on CentOS-5.8. 
In certain conditions I am seeing lot of packets queued in recv queue and not getting processed.
I am monitoring the same using "netstat" command.
While observing the siptrace I found, opensips couldn't  reply to incoming msgs, and if replied, it replies very late.

What sort of params I should observe/optimize to handle this kinda situation(when getting very high traffic on switch) ??
thnx

Comment: were you able to increase the throughput of your server with my suggestions? do you need any more help?

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons for slow UDP/TCP queue processing:

- your OpenSIPS processes are in a deadlock (CPU usage 100% ?)
- not enough memory! Watch the logfile for any memory-related error!

  - `opensipsctl fifo get_statistics shmem:` => to monitor shared memory usage
  - `opensipsctl fifo get_statistics tm:` => to see how many transactions are building up
- not enough processes! consider increasing the number of children

To conclude, OpenSIPS 1.6 is old (from 2006) and unsupported anymore. Some of the above MI commands might not even work. You should consider upgrading to 1.11. It is stable, has lots of great features and it's LTS.